# Multiple await`s in one line (nested async calls)

Tags: javascript, promise, async-await

I could not find any good info on what multiple `await`'s in one line mean or how they should be handled. So I created the following test code (executed in Node):

```js
async function resolveAfterNSeconds(n, value) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(value);
    }, n*1000);
  });
};

async function test(which) {
  const start = new Date().getTime();
  let result;
  switch (which) {
    case 1:
      result = await resolveAfterNSeconds(10, await resolveAfterNSeconds(2, 'done'));
      break;
    case 2:
      result = await resolveAfterNSeconds(2, await resolveAfterNSeconds(10, 'done'));
      break;
    case 3:
      result = await resolveAfterNSeconds(10, resolveAfterNSeconds(2, 'done'));
      break;
    case 4:
      result = await resolveAfterNSeconds(2, resolveAfterNSeconds(10, 'done'));
      break;
    case 5:
      result = resolveAfterNSeconds(10, await resolveAfterNSeconds(2, 'done'));
      break;
    case 6:
      result = resolveAfterNSeconds(2, await resolveAfterNSeconds(10, 'done'));
      break;
  }
  const end = new Date().getTime();
  console.log([which, result, (new Date().getTime()-start)/1000]);
}

test(1); // [1, 'done', 12], as expected
test(2); // [2, 'done', 12], as expected
test(3); // [3, 'done', 10], as expected (kind of)
test(4); // [4, 'done', 10], but expected: [4, Promise, 2]
test(5); // [5, Promise, 2], as expected
test(6); // [6, Promise, 10], as expected
```

I think I do understand why in case 3, `'done'` is returned instead of the corresponding `Promise` - the 2s timeout already has finished by then (am I right?).

However, I do not understand case 4: It seems that the one `await` at the beginning also somehow relates to the inner `Promise`, because otherwise, shouldn't this `Promise` be returned (instead of `'done'`) after 2s?

But if the outer `await` in fact does relate to the inner `Promise` as well, doesn't that imply that cases 1 and 2 are non-sense and should always be replaced with cases 3 and 4 (resp.), so that two or more `await`'s in one line are never useful?

Comment: `resolve(value);` if value is a promise, then the resolved value is the value of the resolved promise: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-promise-constructor *The resolve function that is passed to an executor function accepts a single argument. The executor code may eventually call the resolve function to indicate that it wishes to resolve the associated Promise object. The argument passed to the resolve function represents the eventual value of the deferred action and can be either the actual fulfillment value or another Promise object which will provide the value if it is fulfilled.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I do understand why in case 3, 'done' is returned instead of the corresponding Promise - the 2s timeout already has finished by then (am I right?).

No, it's the same as case 4.

> However, I do not understand case 4: It seems that the one await at the beginning also somehow relates to the inner Promise, because otherwise, shouldn't this Promise be returned (instead of 'done') after 2s?

If you resolve a promise (X) with another promise (Y) then promise X *adopts* the state of promise Y.

> But if the outer await in fact does relate to the inner Promise as well, doesn't that imply that cases 1 and 2 are non-sense and should always be replaced with cases 3 and 4 (resp.),

No. They have different behaviour.

If you `await` a promise (Y) and use its resolved value as an argument to a function that creates another promise (X) then that function won't start running until Y has resolved.

If you don't await it, then it will start running before `Y` has resolved (so the two operations that are wrapped in promises can run in parallel).

Answer (score -4):

Basically, `async/await` is just a wrapper over `Promise`. If you call any `async` function it returns Promise, and calling it with `await` stops execution of main context and waits for `Promise` finishing. But if you call it without `await`, then it will be just a simple function call, the Promise will start execution, but nothing will wait for its end, and the rest of your code will be executed synchronously.

So in your example in case 4 call of `resolveAfterNSeconds` with `await` creates a promise around `resolveAfterNSeconds(2, value)` and call of `resolveAfterNSeconds(10, value)` in parameters without `await` executes `resolveAfterNSeconds(10, value)` synchronously, what leads to passing inner `Promise` as a second parameter.

Hence `await resolveAfterNSeconds(2, value)` stops execution of the main context and `Promise` chain  will be created inside, so the execution will continue only when the whole `Promise` chain will be resolved, and the result of `Promise` chain is `done` - the last resolved value, that comes to `result` variable.

That's why you are getting `done` value;

Comment: Your first paragraph is completely wrong. `await` causes a function to go to sleep until the promise associated with it resolves. It is the `async` keyword that wraps a function in a promise.

Comment: @Quentin Edited, thanks.
It wasn't completely wrong, it just wasn't clear enough.